# Why does this simple float arithmetic property fail to be verified using WP?

Tags: frama-c

I am trying to verify this simple code sample but cannot find what's wrong. I reduced it to the minimal case here:

```
/*@ requires (float)0 <= (float)number < (float)1.0;
    ensures (float)\result == (float)((float)1.0 - (float)number);
    ensures (float)((float)\result + (float)number) == (float)1.0;
    ensures (float)0 < (float)\result <= (float)1.0;
    ensures (float)\result > (float)0;
*/
float complement(float number) {
    return (float)1 - number;
}
```

I would be very thankful for your help.
Additionally, as I found the documentation on floating point verification to be somewhat sparse, is there anything I am overlooking here?

Comment: Which provers did you use to prove your properties? Floating-point support is a very specialized feature, and many solvers are not very strong in this respect.

Comment: I used alt-ergo for this. I am aware of Gappa, but could not install it on my system.

Comment: Tanks for the information. However, after digging a little bit further, I'm afraid that WP support of floating points is currently too rudimentary to be really usable.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway. I was able to prove some other float algorithms fine, though.

Comment: @Virgile, may I ask where you "dug a little bit further" to find this information? I would be interested to see the current state.

Comment: I've add a look at the `Cfloat` WP library (in `$FRAMAC_SHARE/wp/why3`) where you can see that the axiomatization is pretty minimal, and does not build upon Why3's standard library `floating_point.why` file, which means that even if Why3 would be able to take advantage of Gappa's built-in functionalities, WP would not be able to use it directly: one would have to devise a specific driver to do that.